# Solution of $\tan((n+1)x/2) = (n+1)\tan(x/2)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, maxima-minima

I want to calculate the point of maxima of the functions
$$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(\frac{\sin\left((n+1)\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\right)^2$$
lying in the interval $(0,\pi)$. For any $n$ maxima of $f_n(x)$ can be described by the equation 
$$\tan\left((n+1)\frac{x}{2}\right) = (n+1)\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right).$$

This equation can also be transformed to 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor}(-1)^k k {n+1\choose{2k+1}}\tan^{2k}\frac{x}{2}=0.$$

Another form of this equation is 
$$n\sin\left(\frac{(n+2)x}{2}\right) = (n + 2) \sin\left(\frac{nx}{2}\right).$$

The solutions lie in the interval $\left[\frac{2k\pi}{n+1}, \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{n+1}\right], k = 1, 2, 3,\dots,\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor.$ I need solutions in terms of $k$ and $n$. I know that a closed form is quite difficult to obtain but if someone can provide me a series expansion for $x$, it will also be very helpful.

Comment: Try using $e^{ix}=i\sin(x)+\cos(x)$: working with exponential is way much easier than working with goniometric functions

Comment: @gabrielecassese Already tried with no success.

Comment: I got better approximations using Householder's method and methods of higher orders. By the way, computing the equation of the line defined by the bounds of the interval gives a decent estimate too.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Can you please edit your answer to elaborate your comment?

Comment: About which point ?

Comment: `Computing the equation of the line defined by the bounds of the interval gives a decent estimate too.`

Comment: Just compute the value of $y_1=f(x_1)$ with $x_1=\frac{2k\pi}{n+1}$ and $y_2=f(x_2)$ for $x_2=\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{n+1}$. Now, write $y_1=a+b x_1$,  $y_2=a+b x_2$; solve for $(a,b)$. The estimate is $x=-\frac a b$.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not a full answer but it is too long for a comment.*

We can *approximate* the solution using **one** step of Newton method using $$x_0=\frac {(4k+1)\pi}{2(n+1)}$$ corresponding to the midpoint of the interval
$\left[\frac{2k\pi}{n+1}, \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{n+1}\right]$ you properly defined.

$$f(x)=n\sin \left(\frac{1}{2} (n+2) x\right) - (n + 2)\sin\left(\frac{nx}{2}\right)$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2} n (n+2) \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} (n+2) x\right)-\frac{1}{2} n (n+2) \cos
   \left(\frac{n x}{2}\right)$$ $$x_1=x_0-\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}$$

For illustration purposes, I looked at $n=20$; the results are given below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & x_1 & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 0.44543 &    0.42827 \\
 2 & 0.75566 &    0.73630 \\
 3 & 1.05925 &    1.03929 \\
 4 & 1.36089 &    1.34068 \\
 5 & 1.66171 &    1.64137 \\
 6 & 1.96210 &    1.94169 \\
 7 & 2.26225 &    2.24181 \\
 8 & 2.56226 &    2.54179 \\
 9 & 2.86219 &    2.84171
\end{array}
\right)$$ We could do better using Halley's method instead of Newtoon. For the same example the results would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & x_1 & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 0.42261 &    0.42827 \\
 2 & 0.72847 &    0.73630 \\
 3 & 1.03041 &    1.03929 \\
 4 & 1.33117 &    1.34068 \\
 5 & 1.63140 &    1.64137 \\
 6 & 1.93137 &    1.94169 \\
 7 & 2.23120 &    2.24181 \\
 8 & 2.53093 &    2.54179 \\
 9 & 2.83061 &    2.84171
\end{array}
\right)$$

Even if the formulae are quite long, they are fully explicit in terms of $k$ and $n$.